# How could I fix rust Invalid argument?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

when I tried to compile 'rpsgame' rust file, but error appeared and said
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: ...\AppData\Local\Temp\rustcJLJntI\symbols.o: Invalid argument'
This is rpsgame rust file:

**main.rs**

```
use std::io;
use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    println!("1(scissor), 2(rock), 3(paper) pick one of three");
    let mut player = String::new();
    let com = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1..3);
    // 1(scissor), 2(rock), 3(paper)


    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut player)
        .expect("This is not String data");

    let player: u32 = player.trim().parse().expect("Please type a number!");

    if player == com {
        println!("Draw");
    } else if player > com {
        println!("player win");
    } else if player == 1 && com == 3 {
        println!("player win");
    } else {
        println!("com win");
    }

}
```

**cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "rpsgame"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.4"
```

**My rust enviroment variable**

```
CARGO_HOME = E:\Programming engine\Rust compiler\.cargo
RUSTUP_HOME = E:\Programming engine\Rust compiler\.rustup
CARGO_HOME\bin
```

I tried to search about 'x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: symbols.o invalid argument'
but I can't find How to fix 'symbols.o' Invalid argument.

**then**

```
PS E:\Programming_file\Rust\rpsgame> cargo build
   Compiling rpsgame v0.1.0 (E:\Programming_file\Rust\rpsgame)
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustcJLJntI\\symbols.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.10390vvgtim4ju1c.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.14de9oze7zk3b11g.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.1ahxd9fbppz3nz3b.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.1ayabc1ne13g113i.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.1cmx4pwu9l2r7xwt.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.1v6hjqej6dr80xtl.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.1vtmweiibv09hbnk.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2414924rtdi6dxia.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.259mgdu3k0hl6dwc.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2800fp32lu5kxnlz.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2970u5r69ekish94.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2a2w6pwgtosrm2hn.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2d035dqqi5w4fwlp.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2fgezui6gqn99y0o.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2ru8uxwsv3u5aroa.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.2y54rrx4itn9r8og.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.31cmqu4x6l898412.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.3oimq2aq2onugg1d.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.3skn1ebfe5bkqhcf.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.3ve896t58ol5mlzj.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.3vvc0vx31fsegpos.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.4e5i0yu1p6wep6is.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.4gksyz3jmkf71kdr.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.4lwnx0ws48dgfxc8.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.4qfkjpmzdgnboqo8.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.4yezzr1atzu6bcqh.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.56qgw2muiltaoajr.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.5bh2sov4e3vunkqn.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.c4wz8uibdxnpn9e.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.sv05hzossr37yo9.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.tafb1mdfg6mk0pp.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.v5uii002twmbwhw.rcgu.o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.1hmm4v82987xlx3d.rcgu.o" "-L" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps" "-L" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\librand-645f79ba48adb798.rlib" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\librand_chacha-ae45c51e4bd73e9e.rlib" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\libppv_lite86-a7a039e6721accbf.rlib" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\librand_core-de215353438cb627.rlib" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\libgetrandom-229a7c304eef01e5.rlib" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\libcfg_if-3e8038bee036cd59.rlib" 
"E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-583b0c1a8d918e48.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-32bbe0f97d4b5e74.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-b4abf79acd3cfd5f.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-01a39e8be25b0a33.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-4741964b98a78b52.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-ca9aa9ad07d84224.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-77da45e82831415d.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-6b504ee3232db397.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-f23e5590b13d2ba1.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-707623ebc84f4938.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libadler-6c1f623f129f8c4e.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-b83298f4db169fa7.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-24a266989a087673.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-451066e352fc52df.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-f0b9b386ac2b1f89.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust 
compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-aecd3bcc2854e359.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-295042be5ab55e2d.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-427c90bb0249ec1c.rlib" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-efeda5f809566e63.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lbcrypt" "-lkernel32" "-ladvapi32" "-luserenv" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-lbcrypt" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-o" "E:\\Programming_file\\Rust\\rpsgame\\target\\debug\\deps\\rpsgame-5058512a16b0c8f4.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "E:\\Programming engine\\Rust compiler\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\rustcJLJntI\symbols.o: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Your code works for me, so this is probably a problem with your environment. Can you add some more details, in particular how did you install Rust? And can you add the full error message?

Comment: @Jmb I installed rust with rustup-init.exe, and my enviroment variable showed in post, full error message too.

Comment: Maybe try a reinstall with visual studio build tools instead? msvc is the default on windows alongside rust... Are you using msys2? Do you need mingw?